# How do i choose a paper as a reference paper in my thesis?

Tags: thesis

How do i choose a paper as a literature review in my thesis?i mean,there should be a order of choosing a paper as a literature review in our thesis.

For example,i do energy harvesting optimization in communication as research.So i think there are some conditions that the paper ,i choose to be  literature review, should satisfy

1.Communication

2.Energy harvesting

3.Optimize something

4.Because the system model is a little bit similar,so part of our method is similar

I found that my classmate will choose one of literature review paper paper,which their system models are the same , and write what the system method is,what method does it use?what is its advantage and disadvantage.however,because my model is the newest,there is no one use the same or similar model,so i don't know how to choose the good paper as my literature review paper.

I think now i have two options to choose

Option A : Satisfy 1.,3.,and 4. conditions above,however,our system is still not the same,just a little bit similar,and something we want to optimize is not the same!

Option B : Satisfy 1.,2.,and 3.conditions above,and something we want to optimize is not the same!

Which option is better for me when i want to choose a paper as literature review paper?i think there should be an order of choosing,so i can know which paper should i consider first.

Comment: A literature review needs several papers, not just one.

Comment: @SolarMike maybe my problem is unclear,i have edited it

Comment: Yes! literature review needs several papers, not just one.but my classmate will choose one of it to describe,and say what method does this paper use,what is its advantage.However,i don't know how to choose that one

Comment: You need to ask your thesis advisor this question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @scaaahu, it is better to consult your advisor on this matter. However, note that your literature review should be so coherent such that readers of your thesis should clearly understand what has been done in your area prior to your research, what was the gap that wasn't filled and how your research fits into this context.

For instance, if in communication, you study cognitive radio networks; energy harvesting you have used stochastic geometry; and optimization, you have tried to optimize the access probability of cognitive devices, your literature review should reflect all these elements if possible. Then, if not you move a little higher (for instance others have optimized transmit power, not access probability), then you include that and emphasize that access probability optimization has not been addressed which constitutes your problem. Then it might be necessary to include other research which has used energy harvesting in cognitive radio but has not used stochastic geometry if you find that pertinent to your research. Sometimes, that could depend on how you would like to formulate your problem and the kind of objectives that can be achieved by each method.

To understand how to order these in your thesis, I suggest you also look at very good papers that have been published in your area and how they coherently present the ideas and concepts within the introduction and literature review.

Comment: i agree with what you said "literature review should be so coherent",the option A and B are actually "uncoherent",so i don't know how to choose that paper